# How to use the value of custom variable in vuetify 3.0?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Here is my vuetify configuration

```
const vuetify = createVuetify({
  components,
  directives,
  theme: {
    defaultTheme: 'light',
    themes: {
      dark: {
        colors: {
          background: '#000000',
          primary: '#23252B',
          'primary-1': '#1B1C21',
          'primary-2': '#141519',
          error: '#B00020',
          info: '#0017D0',
          success: '#4CAF50',
          warning: '#FB8C00',
        },
      },
      light: {
        colors: {
          background: '#EEF2F5',
          primary: '#FFFFFF',
          'primary-1': '#DEE2FF',
          'primary-2': '#141519',
          error: '#B00020',
          info: '#0017D0',
          success: '#4CAF50',
          warning: '#FB8C00',
          label: '#555555'
        },
        sizes: {
          'account-card': '500px',
          'account-list-card': '380px'
        }
      },
    },
  },
})
```

When i want to use colors attributes in my style I used

```
.div {
  color: rgb(var(--v-theme-primary))
}
```

and that's work

But I want to use the value of `account-card` by exemple, how can I use it inside style?

I tried

- rgb(var(--v-sizes-account-card))
- var(--v-sizes-account-card)

Both doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Vuetify theme does not have `sizes` property. You can't override them.
If you want to use `--v-sizes-account-card` variable you need to create it in you "main" scss file like this:

```
:root {
  --v-sizes-account-card: 500px;
  --v-sizes-account-list-card: 380px;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
.div {
  width: var(--v-sizes-account-card)
}
```

Comment: So how can I manage dark & light mode with your approch?
I mean, if the mode is dark, width takes the value of `v-sizes-account-card` in dark, and if the mode is light, it takes the value in light

Comment: you want to change the card size according to the mode? you can add any colors to "colors" object. and as I see you already did this.